# Join Serial Data Seperated by Newlines?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, string

I have two Arduinos connected through Bluetooth. One sends a string of data similar to `506:507:1\r\n`. The data can vary similar to `0:1000:0\r\n`. I already have functions to break that string down into three variables. I send it from one Arduino over Bluetooth and the second Arduino receives it through `Serial`. The only problem is that the second Arduino receives this:

```
5
0
6
:
5
0
7
:
1
"\n"
```

At the end it adds a space at the end (`"\n"`) How can I parse this data back into a string similar to `506:507:1\r\n` that can still vary in length?

Comment: Read this: https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/01/reading-serial-on-the-arduino/

Comment: I don't see what the problem is?
Though, you do seem to miss the `\r`?
And I don't see the `space` at the end? You can easily make it a string by adding the characters to the string, until you receive your end character `\n`?

Maybe `https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/ReadStringUntil` is an easy to use, "all in one" solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

Simply reverse the steps you took on the sending side.

- Create a `char` array of sufficient size as well as an index variable to keep track of your position within the array. An Arduino String may be more convenient, though they can cause **a lot** of problems.
- In a loop, use `available()` to wait for incoming chars and add them to the array you've created, using your index variable.
- Keep going in the loop, while checking for that unique character (\n, perhaps) that signals the end of a packet. Add this last byte to the array and then terminate the string with null or `\0`.

If you want to re-use the array for another packet, simply set the index variable to 0 and continue.